# NativeScript - Cannot fit requested classes in a single dex file

Tags: android, nativescript

I am working on an app using the latest version of NativeScript with Angular. I have added most of the pro-ui plugins to my project and added the Firbase plugin.

When I run “tns run android” I get the error:

“D8: Cannot fit requested classes in a single dex file. Try supplying a main-dex list.”

Also, it takes over 5 minutes to build. I have been doing some searching but I cannot find what is causing this problem. Does anyone know what is wrong?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

After much trial and error I have finally come to a solution. All other answers I've read have said that the `multiDexEnabled` property must be set to `true` in the android project's `build.gradle` file.

I wasn't sure how to do this for NativeScript though since the platforms folder is not committed to version control and can be potentially overwritten.

However, in `your_project_root/app/App_resources/Android` there are two files, `settings.gradle` and `settings.json`.

`settings.gradle` is used to generate your projects's `build.gradle` file from the properties you set in `settings.json`.

So, to the `defaultConfig` string template in `settings.gradle` I added:

```
if(__multiDexEnabled__) {
    multiDexEnabled = __multiDexEnabled__
}
```

And to the JSON object defined in `settings.json` I added:

```
"multiDexEnabled": true
```

After that I deleted my project's platforms folder and ran:

```
> tns platforms add android
> tns run android
```

And my app started up on my phone with no problems.

Comment: Still needed and working in 2020 on {NS}6.3.1. Thanks Graham!

Comment: Works perfectly! This is still needed in 2021 on {N}8.

Answer (score 4):

Go to the path 
**platforms/app/build.gradle** (careful **NOT** /platform/build.gradle)
and add the line **multiDexEnabled true**

```
...    
defaultConfig {
            def manifest = new XmlSlurper().parse(file(android.sourceSets.main.manifest.srcFile))
            def minSdkVer = manifest."uses-sdk"."@android:minSdkVersion".text() ?: 17
            minSdkVersion minSdkVer
            targetSdkVersion computeTargetSdkVersion()
            ndk {
                if (onlyX86) {
                    abiFilters 'x86'
                } else {
                    abiFilters 'x86', 'x86_64', 'armeabi-v7a', 'arm64-v8a'
                }
            }
            multiDexEnabled true
            dexOptions {
                jumboMode = true
            }
        }
...
```

Comment: Every build will wipe out your changes.

Answer (score 3):

I have solved this by
Just adding **multiDexEnabled true** into your **app.gradle** under **android->defaultConfig**